# Event defined as particle collision — Mermin's "third postulate"

Tags: special-relativity

Let us define an event in a particular inertial reference frame by a collision of two particles. Is this definition invariant under Lorentz boosting to a different frame?

I am trying to make sense of claims made [here](https://youtu.be/v9wXnlB4fS0?t=2205) and [here](https://youtu.be/v9wXnlB4fS0?t=2875) (the "third postulate" is Mermin's  statement discussed [here](https://youtu.be/v9wXnlB4fS0?t=1027)).

Do we really have to conduct additional experiments to validate this "third postulate"?

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of two distinct lines determines a point. (Think of it as the solution of a system of equations.)

Under a rotation, the lines are transformed to another set of lines
and the intersection point is transformed to the intersection of the new lines.
Try it with a rotation matrix.

An analogous thing happens for a Galilean boost transformation and for a Lorentz boost transformation. So, a collision event between two inertial particles in one inertial frame is a collision event in a different inertial frame.

Try them with their respective boost matrices.

I am not familiar with the claims made in the video.

Is there a peer-reviewed reference?